# How do I know my workspace was syncing to a label?

Tags: perforce

I have multiple workspaces syncing to different labels for some experiments. How can I know if a specific workspace syncing to which label later?

Comment: You'll need to provide more context (and possibly more tags).  As is, I have no idea what technology these workspaces or labels are related to.

Comment: My question is related to Perforce revision control.

Answer (score 2):

You can't know for certain, since it's possible for the label to have changed since you synced, it's possible for two labels to have the same contents and be functionally identical, it's possible for individual files to have been synced to independent revisions since the sync to a label, et cetera.

That said, you can do:

```
p4 sync -n @LABEL
```

and observe whether any files are reported as being different relative to that label.  If you do this for each label you can see which label(s) you're in sync with, or most closely in sync with.

Comment: Thanks, Sam. "p4 sync -n @LABEL" did help me here.